# Some PDF files open in PhantomPDF, others in Chromium browser

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, pdf, chromium

In Windows 10's Windows Explorer, when I double click on PDF files, some PDF files consistently open in a Chromium browser, while others consistently open in PhantomPDF.  I want PhantomPDF to be the default app, and that is what I set it to.  I don't even use Chromium.  **What would cause some files to consistently open in Chromium?**

Details:

- The file extensions are *.pdf
- I open them by double-clicking in the Windows Explorer
- *Also* if I double-click a PDF file attachment in an email (Outlook 2019 desktop), it also opens in Chromium
- For the misbehaving PDF files in Explorer, I cannot seem to re-select PhantomPDF as the default app.  I right-click the file and choose `Open with` **->** `Choose another app`, but get the following message

> The file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action.  Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page

- I can open the `Default apps` system settings and click `Choose default apps by file type`, but PhantomPDF is already chosen for `*.pdf` files
- On the other hand, if I right click a file that doesn't misbehave, I can choose PhantomPDF, and enable the checkbox that makes it the default (even though it already shows as the default)

**Troubleshooting**

I opened the PDF files with `Vim` and saw that the well behaved file is PDF-1.4 while the misbehaving files are PDF-1.6 and PDF-1.7.  My organization's PhantomPDF is version 9.6.  I briefly thought that the message about not having an app associated with certain PDF files might simply be Windows 10's erroneous interpretation of PhantomPDF's inability to open PDF-1.6 and up.  Subsequently, however, I have confirmed that if I first open PhantomPDF and use it to open the misbehaving files, it opens them just fine.

**Afternote**

I am beginning to suspect HP Sure Click.  The tooltip for Chromium icon on the taskbar says HP Sure Click, and web searching reveals that it uses Chromium.  There is plenty of evidence that HP Sure Click will cause problems, but I'll hold off on uninstalling for now.  With all the time lost to this problem, I just don't have the time for further time consuming battles and the uncertainties in how to follow through correctly.  If I really can't live with Chromium, I'll open PhantomPDF and use it to open the PDF of interest.

Comment: What are the file extensions? How are you opening the files? I know you say "Windows Explorer" and "PDF", but there are different types of PDFs, and there are different ways to open files in Explorer, and knowing the differences and their outcomes matters when diagnosing things like this.

Comment: I added the details to the originally posted question.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so when you double click in Explorer it opens in Phantom, and when you double click in Outlook it opens in Chromium?

Comment: Not quite.  I reworded the question to make it clearer.  Thanks again.

Comment: This computer belongs to a business?

Comment: Yes, but a very bureaucratic one, so IT support cannot be assumed.  Not their fault, they contend with the same process challenges as everyone else.

Comment: Answering questions about business owned computers is difficult for many reasons. A few of them are that the issue may be related to policies set by IT, or the settings needed to change are protected from modification, and the computer and it's software belongs to someone else, and they are responsible for fixing it and keeping it running. For these reasons we cannot entertain this question here though. You need to go to your IT folks. Issues dealing with them do not change that fact.

Comment: I understand that the solution may be out of bounds to a pion in a corporation, but I was really hoping to understand the cause.  I then know whether it is an IT support issue or (not a good thing) or something a pion can fix.  I find that an overwhelming majority of issues fall in the latter category.  As well, not all employer machines are locked down.